# C# and Kinect v2: Merge Kinect-pointcloud with pointcloud of 3D-object

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, point-clouds, kinect-v2

Currently I'm working on a C#-project to merge color and depth information that can be retrieved from the Kinect-v2 device by using the Kinect SDK, with information that can be gathered from 3-dimensional object-files (.obj, .stl, and so on..). As a result I'd like to create a pixel-pointcloud that contains the information of both - the coordinates and color information from the Kinect device aswell as the information from the object file.

**What I've done so far?**

- I managed to set up two arrays of pixels `Pixel[]` that hold the needed data
  (X/Y/Z-coordinates, as well as the regarding color-information RGB).
- One array contains the Kinect-data while the other one contains the
  data of the object-file.

  ```
  public class Pixel 
  {
       public double X { get; set; }
       public double Y { get; set; }
       public double Z { get; set; }
       public byte R { get; set; }
       public byte G { get; set; }
       public byte B { get; set; }
  }
  ```

To get color and depth information and to set up the Kinect-array, I first used the Kinect-SDK's `MultiSourceFrameReader` class to aquire a `MultiSourceFrame` ..

```
MultiSourceFrame multiSourceFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame();
```

.. so that I can aquire the color/depth frames right after that:

```
DepthFrame depthFrame = multiSourceFrame.DepthFrameReference.AcquireFrame();
ColorFrame colorFrame = multiSourceFrame.ColorFrameReference.AcquireFrame();
```

With the methods `.CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray()` and `.CopyFrameDataToArray()` I get the frame data for RGB and depth information, which then are mapped to a `CameraSpacePoint[]`array with the `CoordinateMapper`'s `.MapColorPointsToCameraSpace()` method to extract the X/Y/Z-coordinates within the camera-space. With this array and the frame data I can set the `Pixel[]` array that holds all information of the "Kinect-pointcloud".

To set up the "pointcloud" for the 3D-object I used a 3rd-party library to load the object and to extract its X/Y/Z-coordinates and color information.

**Next step**
My next step would be to merge both of these pointclouds but thats were I'm stuck. I somehow would have to map or resize the 3D-information (X/Y/Z) of the one pointcloud so that it fits to the 3D-information of the other pointcloud as they are both scaled differently. This leads to my questions:

**My Questions**

- How can I scale the object pointcloud to make it fit into the Kinect-pointcloud?
- How do I find out which pixel of the object overwrites a pixel within the Kinect-pointcloud? (The resulting pointcloud should not change its size of 1920*1080 pixels)
- Are there any libraries capable of doing that?

**Additional Information**
A coordinate within the Kinect-pointcloud looks like: 
 - X: 1.4294..  
 - Y: 0.9721..  
 - Z: 2.1650..

A coordinate within the 3D-object looks like:  
 - X:   0.8331..
 - Y: -16.0591..
 - Z:  26.8001..